# Personalize Shiny interface

Tags: r, shiny

how can i personalize my shiny application, by default, siderPanel is placed in the topleft, mainPanel in the centre anf if i had somme summary it's in the bottom...
In my application, siderpanel, mainPanel and verbatimTextOutput are one above the other, can you help me to replace it ?

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(

    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "bootstrap.css"),
    tags$style(HTML("
      @import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Cabin:400,700');
    "))
  ),

  headerPanel(h1("ReprÃ©sentation de Weibull", 
                 style = "font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        font-weight: 500; line-height: 1.1; 
        color: #00BFFF;")),
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
    column(3,
    sidebarPanel(
      wellPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choisir votre 1er fichier tabulÃ©"), 

        checkboxInput("fit_weibull", label = "Ajuster une loi de Weibull", value = FALSE),

        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.fit_weibull == true",
          uiOutput("slider"))
      ),
      wellPanel(
        fileInput("file2", "Choisir votre 2e fichier tabulÃ©"), 
        checkboxInput("fit_weibull2", label = "Ajuster une loi de Weibull", value = FALSE),
                conditionalPanel(
                  condition = "input.fit_weibull2 == true",
                  uiOutput("slider2"))  
      )
    )),
    column(9,
    mainPanel(
      list(tags$head(tags$style("body {background-color: #F8F8FF; }"))),
      plotOutput("plot.weibull"),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.fit_weibull == true",
        verbatimTextOutput("km_lim"),
        verbatimTextOutput("coefficients")

      ),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.fit_weibull2 == true",
        verbatimTextOutput("km_lim2"),
        verbatimTextOutput("coefficients2")

      )
    ))

  )
)
```

Comment: Please I need help, i got something but is's very ugly on the screen !

Comment: problem solved ! i used "fixedRow" !

Comment: you should answer your own question so someone else might find it useful if they find your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is solved with CSS, you can change the properties of each element. Remember the id of each panel and with this, you can fix whatever you want. Nevertheless this is a hard working task, I believe that is better to personalize with a package like shinythemes or shinydashboard.

This packages help you to customize your web application but if you want to move the position of one of this elements, you will have to change the CSS properties.

For example:

```
             float: right
             width: 70%
             height:10%
             margin: 0 0 0 0 (top-right-bottom-left)
```